# Why does the flag box say "404" when I use it?

Tags: bug, flags

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18723430/2765681) then click "Flag" then click "It doesn't belong here" and I get a 404 error

> [image]

What's the deal?

Comment: FYI, you have to use one of the required tags, not all 4 of them. Pick the one that fits best.

Comment: Why are you flagging your own question as "it doesn't belong here or is duplicate".  If you don't think it belongs (and it doesn't), just delete it

Comment: @psubsee2003 If the question had an upvoted answer, or the OP wanted to flag it for migration to the proper SE site (while maintaining answers and comments), or the OP found a duplicate and was trying to be responsible in flagging it as such... this problem would exist in a way that can't be solved with a self delete.

Comment: @MichaelT of course, but I was referring to this specific question.  It had no answers, numerous downvotes and was well on its way to being closed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I was just testing the flag dialog... sorry.

Comment: @user2765681 that's no problem - was just making sure you knew that you could delete it yourself.  Although typically, you want to avoid flagging posts you have the capability to deal with yourself.